# Почему задержка в одно надатие?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Учу Cheakbox и разбираю код с помощью откладки, и увидела непонятную для меня штуку, что в переменную `allchecked`  не сразу добавляется/удаляется значения cheakbox, те чтобы в массив занеслась переменная с cheakbox, нужно удалить/добавить другой cheakbox, грубо говоря массив обновляется, через одно действие, а не сразу. Почему так?
Код:

```js
//import React from "react";

const App = () => {
   const [allchecked, setAllChecked] = React.useState([]);
   function handleChange(e) {
      if (e.target.checked) {
         setAllChecked([...allchecked, e.target.value]); //Вот здесь массив не сразу обновляется почему?
      } else {
         setAllChecked(allchecked.filter((item) => item !== e.target.value));
      }
   }
   return (
      <div>
         <h4>
            {" "}
            Creating the {" "}
            <i>
               {" "}
               Custom controlled checkbox and handling the multiple checkboxes
               {" "}
            </i>{" "} in the React application {" "}
         </h4>
         <div>
            <input value = "One" type = "checkbox" onChange = {handleChange} />
            <span> One </span>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input value = "Two" type = "checkbox" onChange = {handleChange} />
            <span> Two </span>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input value = "Three" type = "checkbox" onChange = {handleChange} />
            <span> Three </span>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input value = "Four" type = "checkbox" onChange = {handleChange} />
            <span> Four </span>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input value = "Five" type = "checkbox" onChange = {handleChange} />
            <span> Five </span>
         </div>
         <div>The all checked values are {allchecked.join(" , ")}</div>
      </div>
   );
};
// export default App; 

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Comment: В твоем примере все обновляется с одного клика... А в том конкретном месте ты изменений сразу не увидишь, т.к. изменение стейта асинхронное действо и оно произойдет не в том месте, а потом.

Comment: В App добавьте код: `useEffect(() => { console.log(allchecked); }, [allchecked]);` как произойдет изменение переменной allchecked, она будет выведена в консоль с актуальным состоянием.